# How python import works in this particular example

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, attributes, python-import

In the below code how are we able to call `packA.a1.a1_func()` in `start.py` ? From my understanding, to be able to do this, we would need to have the statement `from packA import a1` in `test/packA/__init__.py`. In the current setting, I believe only `packA.packA_func()` and `packA.a1_func()` would be valid statements in `start.py`.

In other words, why does `packA`'s namespace contain both `'a1'` and `'a1_func'` and not only `'a1_func'` ? ( have verified with dir() )

Thank you!

**test/packA/a1.py**

```
def a1_func():
    print("running a1_func()")
```

**test/packA/**init**.py**

```
## this import makes a1_func directly accessible from packA.a1_func
from packA.a1 import a1_func

def packA_func():
    print("running packA_func
```

**test/start.py**

```
import packA  # "import packA.a1" will work just the same

packA.packA_func()
packA.a1_func()
packA.a1.a1_func()
```

output of running python start.py:

```
running packA_func()
running a1_func()
running a1_func
```

Source : https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html

Comment: It would be helpful if whoever downvoted actually explained why they did so. I do not understand why. I have stated what I know so far and what I expect. Any hints as to what are my misunderstandings in python imports would be really appreciated.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include your code as a [formatted code block](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Answer (score -1):

@gateway2745 in start.py all the three calls are working because you have already imported the

a1_func in the packA/**init**.py So it will directly work using packA.ai_func() just like your packA_func()

```
from packA.a1 import a1_func()
```

Comment: I understood that "packA.a1_func()" works fine. My question is why does "packA.a1.a1_func()" work?

Comment: @gateway2745 I wish I could give a indepth answer but here is what I know:
Python modules now implement a module.__spec__ attribute. You can check it by print(packA.__spec__). This attribute contains a search location for submodules. which is the dir packA/. 
So I think the module loader will search the module in this dir for the import from packA.a1 imort ai_func()

Here are some links to read more details: https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/import.html#loading  
And here is more on import: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html